# Applying custom module chrome under J3.3.3

Tags: module, joomla-3.3.x, module-style

I have created a custom module chrome for my 3.3.1 website and it was working perfectly. I have just updated my website to 3.3.3 and my module.php got overriden in the process (promise, it won't happen again!). The module.php seems to be coded in a slightly different way so I have adapted the chrome php to reflect this change, but I can't make my module chrome work.

Thanks a lot for your help! (sorry for all the code below, I cut it down to the specific part concerning the module chrome)

This is in template/index.php

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="megarounded"/>
```

The template/html/module.php I had in my Joomla 3.3.1

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<?php
function modChrome_megarounded($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{ ?>
        <div class="megamod module<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
            <div class="megabox">
                <div class="megaboxouter">
                    <div class="megaboxinner">
                        <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
                            <h6><?php echo $module->title; ?></h6>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $module->content; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

The template/html/module.php I have now in my Joomla 3.3.3

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
function modChrome_megarounded($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    if ($module->content)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"megamod" . htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')) . "\">";
            echo "<div class=\"megabox\">";
                echo "<div class=\"megaboxouter\">";
                    echo "<div class=\"megaboxinner\">";
        if ($module->showtitle)
        {
            echo "<h6>" . $module->title . "</h6>";
        }
        echo $module->content;
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

My website is [here](http://www.rscmovement.org/en/): you can see the module chrome style I want on the right column around `The RSC in brief` (I have added the class directly in the index.php so for this module I didn't use the correct way of adding the module chrome). I am supposed to have this chrome apply to the user-1 position also (around all the greyish rectangles of `Last articles`).

Any idea why my chrome isn't working? Thanks a lot!

I am seen [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome), but I didn't help me much

**Update:**
 based on Beez5 I have tried this but still no success:

```
 function modChrome_megarounded($module, &$params, &$attribs)
 {
    if ($module->content)
    {?>
        <div class="megamod <?php echo htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));?>">
            <div class="megabox">
                <div class="megaboxouter">
                    <div class="megaboxinner">
        <?php if ($module->showtitle) : ?>
        <h6><?php echo $module->title; ?></h6>
         <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $module->content; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the Protostar template, it uses *modules.php* so try changing your file from:

`module.php` to `modules.php`

Note the `s` on the end.

Also, on your `jdoc` includes, try adding a space before the forward slash at the end.

`style="megarounded"/>` to `style="megarounded" />`

Hope this helps

Comment: So simple and so stupid! Thanks a lot Lodder!